# final hashmap are thread safe

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, final

```
public class MapDem {

 final HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

 public HashMap<Integer,Integer> getMap(){
     return map;
 }
 public void putValue(int key,int value){
     map.put(key,value);
 }

 public static void main(String args[]){
    MapDem demo = new MapDem();
    new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
                demo.putValue(1, 10);

        }

    }).start();

    new Thread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            demo.putValue(1, 10);

        }

    }).start();

System.out.println(demo.getMap().size());

}
```

}

Are `final` fields inherently thread-safe? In the above code the `map` variable is marked as `final`, does that mean that it is thread-safe?

If the variable is *not* thread-safe I expect that the output from the `main`-method should be a "2" but I am getting either "1" or "0"

**EDIT**

If I declare the variable using the `volatile` keyword, i.e.

```
volatile HashMap<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
```

the `map` variable is seemingly not thread-safe, why is this? However the below method seems to work, why is this?

```
public  synchronized void putValue(int key,int value){
    if(map.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println("hello");
        map.put(key,value);     
}
```

Will using `Collections.unmodifiableMap(map)` work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thread Safe - final local method variable passed on to threads?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11824264/thread-safe-final-local-method-variable-passed-on-to-threads)

Comment: I don't think your code is thread safe because the two threads you create could interleave and modify the map at the same time.

Comment: i have gone through the link but i am not clear that is why i have posted the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test ist faulty. If two `value`s are stored with the same `key`, [`HashMap.put(K key, V value)` will overwrite the former `value` with the later](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put-K-V-). Thus, even without concurrency, your "test" will return a size of `1`.

Code:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MapDem {

    final HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    public HashMap<Integer, Integer> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void putValue(int key, int value) {
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MapDem demo = new MapDem();

        demo.putValue(1, 10);
        demo.putValue(1, 10);

        System.out.println(demo.getMap().size());
    }
}
```

Output ([<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/Jrcfgz)):

```
1
```

The fact that sometimes one can see a size of `0` is due to the lack of blocking constructs. You should wait for completion of both `Thread`s before querying the size of yur map by calling [`join()` on your `Thread`-objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join--).

```
            Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    demo.putValue(1, 10);

                }

            });
            t1.start();

            Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    demo.putValue(1, 10);

                }

            });
            t2.start();

            try {
                t1.join();
                t2.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(demo.getMap().size());
```

[As mentioned by @SachinSarawgi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41342778/4216641), `final` does not make your code thread-safe and [as further explained by @assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41342680/4216641), `volatile` does not cut it in this case.

If you need a thread-safe Hashmap, use [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

If you are determined to write your own thread-safe implementation of the [`Map` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), I recommend [Oracle's Lesson on Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) to start with, followed by [Brian Goetz's "Java Concurrency in Practice"](http://jcip.net/) and maybe a little bit of [Javier Fernández González' "Mastering Concurrency Programming with Java 8"](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/mastering-concurrency-programming-java-8).

Answer (score 1):

The direct immediate answer to your question is: no, the **final** keyword does not make fields *thread safe*.

That keyword only tells the compiler that it has to ensure that there is exactly **one** value assigned to that field (not zero or multiple assignments).

You know, there are reasons why *getting multi-threaded code* **correct** is considered **hard**.

The essence of correct multi-threading is: when some **state** can be updated by one thread, but is used (or updated) by other threads .. to make sure that you only get those state changes that you want to see.

Long story short: you have a lot of learning to do; a good starting point would be [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

What is thread safe is the access to the `map` variable: all threads reading that variable will see the same object reference.

However the operations on the HashMap (get/put) are not thread safe and this has nothing to do with the fact that `map` is final or not.

So your code is not thread safe unless you add some concurrency control around the `putValue` method - for example by making it `synchronized`.

Comment: I should get answer as 2 why 1 or 0 is comming and declaring it as final .Final are thread safe.

Comment: Why do you think you should get 2? HashMap is not thread safe - that means that the result of concurrent operations on the map is undefined. 0, 1, 2 or -13 would all be legal outputs.

Comment: @coder25 Your assumption is wrong. As assylias already explained, the object itself is thread safe, but not its fields. So the hashmap object (the reference) is thread-safe, but any operation you do on it is not thread safe unless you use a `synchronized` block. `final` is not a magic keyword that turns object to thread-safe objects.

Comment: if i use a volatile variable then also it is not working.with synchronized it works

Comment: @coder25 volatile, like final, modifies the semantics of the variable to which it is applied, not to the underlying object.

Answer (score 0):

Making reference variable final make sure that the reference variable cant change the object reference it has been assigned to.

But the value of the object could change. Same thing is happening here your object value could change. Now the code which change the value need to be synchronized.
You can get rid of all the synchronization problem by using `ConcurrentHashMap`. You can read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html).

Using `ConcurrentHashMap` make sure that every write operation on the object should be handled by one thread at a time. Also it optimize the reading of `HashMap` too. It divide the `HashMap` into block and different threads may read from different blocks.