# How can Runnable modify a final local variable

Tags: java, android, multithreading, final, volatile

I was trying to find out when my user interface is running and had the clever idea of posting a runnable to the uiThread whose only job would be to set a flag.  I tried to use a `volatile` keyword on `uiIsRunning` but eclipse won't allow that and I don't understand that yet.

But what is amazing to me is when I tried the code below without the final modifier on `uiIsRunning`, I was told correctly that I could only use a local variable in an embedded class if that local variable is `final`.  So I made `uiIsRunning final` and much to my surprise, Eclipse is totally fine with my line `uiIsRunning = true;`, that is Eclipse thinks it is fine for me to be setting the value of my `final` variable inside this nested class!

If anybody can tell me what I need to do to get the action I want: set a flag to false in my current thread which is then set to true when the thread I am posting it to executes it, I would be grateful.

```
        final boolean uiIsRunning = false;
        uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                uiIsRunning = true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424753/why-do-variables-passed-to-runnable-need-to-be-final

Comment: Why would you share a local variable to multiple threads?

Comment: You can't. The code doesn't compile. Not a real question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is peculiar that you seem to be able to modify a `final` variable. But more to the point, what you can do in your case is the following:

```
public class SurroundingActivity extends Activity {

    volatile boolean uiIsRunning = false;
    private Handler uiHandler;

    void someMethod () { 
        uiHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SurroundingActivity.this.uiIsRunning = true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he cannot modify it. Local fields, to have visibility inside other threads declared inside the same method, need to be declared final.

Comment: Two code-snippets ran together; clarified.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using it as flag, you should use the volatile keyword and set it as a variable of your class(instead of a local variable, as you did). Caution, a volatile variable should only be modified by a unique thread. If you want to modify it by more than one thread, you should take a look at synchronisation or atomic objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can access a field within multiple threads by instancing it outside your method (this way, not a "local variable").

```
private int sharedInt = 0;

public void someMethod() {

    // sharedInt will be visible inside this thread.
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {....});

}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It's almost the same as accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

> How can Runnable modify a final local variable

It can't. Your code sample doesn't compile unless the variable is a member variable, not a local variable.

```
cannot assign a value to final variable uiIsRunning
```

Not a real question.