# Local variable a defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final

Tags: java

```
@Test
public void test() throws IOException{
    int a = 5;
    Pipe pipe = Pipe.open();
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pipe.sink();
            a++;
        }
    }).start();
}
```

why `a++` reports an error :

> Local variable a defined in an enclosing scope must be final or
>   effectively final

but `pipe.sink()` doesn't ?
i'm using jdk8.0

Comment: You are not reassigning the value of `pipe`, so the variable is effectively final.

Comment: because it has to... declare a as a class member....

Comment: This is a good explanation of your "WHY" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424753/why-do-variables-passed-to-runnable-need-to-be-final Hope it helps..!!

Comment: thanks,i understand!

Comment: @ligen To be clear, "effectively final" means that the variable itself is not marked as `final`, but the compiler is smart enough to detect that the variable never changes in the code. (Note that in case of references only the reference *itself* is not changed, the members of the object might be changed.)